# convert XML formats

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML with format as below in a string:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
- <soap:Body>
- <GetUserLinksResponse xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService">
- <GetUserLinksResult>
- <QuickLinkData>
  <Name>System 1</Name> 
  <Group>General</Group> 
  <Privacy>Private</Privacy> 
  <Url>https://url1.com</Url> 
  <ID>6500</ID> 
  </QuickLinkData>
- <QuickLinkData>
  <Name>System 2</Name> 
  <Group>General</Group> 
  <Privacy>Private</Privacy> 
  <Url>https://url2.com</Url> 
  <ID>6499</ID> 
  </QuickLinkData>
- <QuickLinkData>
  <Name>System 3</Name> 
  <Group>Work</Group> 
  <Privacy>Private</Privacy> 
  <Url>http://url3.com</Url> 
  <ID>6845</ID> 
  </QuickLinkData>
  </GetUserLinksResult>
  </GetUserLinksResponse>
  </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

which I want in format as below using xslt or in c#:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<root>
<Group>
<Value>General</Value>
<Item>
 <ID>6500</ID>
 <Name>System 1</Name>
 <Url>https://url1.com</Url>
</Item>
<Item>
 <ID>6499</ID>
 <Name>System 2</Name>
 <Url>https://url2.com</Url>
</Item>
</Group>
<Group>
<Value>Work</Value>
<Item>
 <ID>6845</ID>
 <Name>System 3</Name>
 <Url>https://url3.com</Url>
</Item>
</Group>
</root>
```

There could be multiple groups
How can I achieve this in c# (using xslt or any other process)

Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This short and simple transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService"
 exclude-result-prefixes="x">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kGroupByVal" match="x:Group" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match=
   "x:Group[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kGroupByVal',.)[1])]">
  <Group>
   <Value><xsl:value-of select="."/></Value>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kGroupByVal',.)/.." mode="inGroup"/>
  </Group>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="x:QuickLinkData" mode="inGroup">
  <Item>
   <ID><xsl:value-of select="x:ID"/></ID>
   <Name><xsl:value-of select="x:Name"/></Name>
   <Url><xsl:value-of select="x:Url"/></Url>
  </Item>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<soap:Envelope
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetUserLinksResponse
          xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService">
            <GetUserLinksResult>
                <QuickLinkData>
                    <Name>System 1</Name>
                    <Group>General</Group>
                    <Privacy>Private</Privacy>
                    <Url>https://url1.com</Url>
                    <ID>6500</ID>
                </QuickLinkData>
                <QuickLinkData>
                    <Name>System 2</Name>
                    <Group>General</Group>
                    <Privacy>Private</Privacy>
                    <Url>https://url2.com</Url>
                    <ID>6499</ID>
                </QuickLinkData>
                <QuickLinkData>
                    <Name>System 3</Name>
                    <Group>Work</Group>
                    <Privacy>Private</Privacy>
                    <Url>http://url3.com</Url>
                    <ID>6845</ID>
                </QuickLinkData>
            </GetUserLinksResult>
        </GetUserLinksResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<Group>
   <Value>General</Value>
   <Item>
      <ID>6500</ID>
      <Name>System 1</Name>
      <Url>https://url1.com</Url>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <ID>6499</ID>
      <Name>System 2</Name>
      <Url>https://url2.com</Url>
   </Item>
</Group>
<Group>
   <Value>Work</Value>
   <Item>
      <ID>6845</ID>
      <Name>System 3</Name>
      <Url>http://url3.com</Url>
   </Item>
</Group>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the **[Muenchian Grouping Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response Thank you for the implementation it worked well...

Answer (score 0):

You should use: [Linq to xml](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=564)

First of all, i would prepare set of collections or better, new classes: Group and Item.

On the second stage parse the source file, fill collections with data.

And at last, from these class collections generate the desired file structure using linq to xml.

Good luck!